# salvar em um arquivo dados via teclado em javaScript

Tags: javascript

se possível me ajude com minha duvida, estou mais perdido que cego em tiroteio,

olha eu gostaria de fazer uma pesquisa que o usuário digita-se via prompt e o mesmo fosse somando, no final eu gostaria de salvar em arquivo por exemplo em text para que eu possa ter esse dados salvos e não se perde, já que o que esta em variaveis serão perdidos em futuras interações, como por exemplo abrir e fechar o programa.

segue abaixo o código, esta bem básico, ainda irei colocar um comando DO WHILE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">



<script>
var otima=0
var boa=0
var pessima=0
var regular=0
var op=prompt("Escolha opção:")

switch(op){

    case '1': otima=otima+1

            break
    case '2': boa=boa+1

            break
    case '3': pessima=pessima+1

            break

    case '4': resular+regular+1

            break
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</htm>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Mas você vai fazer no navegador ou no `Node.js`?

Comment: Diego, poderia esclarecer melhor o contexto de como isso será usado? Irá integrar com alguma aplicação que já existe?

Comment: Boa tarde, não sera usado somente no navegador mesmo, em resumo, via prompt entro com os dados ele, soma e o propósito que os dados possam ser arquivo em um doc.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta não esta muito clara, não esta dando para entender se você quer guardar os dados para usar eles na pagina em um outro momento, por exemplo: ao voltar a acessar a pagina, ou se realmente você quer fazer um download de arquivo para por exemplo gerar um 'report'.

Se você quiser salvar os dados para utilizar-los em um outro momento na pagina você pode fazer como mostrado pelo [@user1331413](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/386390/3774) utilizando [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) ou [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Agora se você quiser baixar um arquivo uma das formas pode ser gerar um `dataURI`, para isso vou utilizar a função [`btoa`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp) para converter a string em base64 como mostrado abaixo.

```js
// String que sera salva.
let texto = "Vou salvar esse texto como arquivo de texto, teste de acentos áãõíçô";

// Gerar link de download dataURI
let link = "data: text; base64,"+btoa(texto);
// tipo do arquivo ^             ^ gerar base64

// Adicionar link na pagina, para download
document.body.innerHTML += "<a href='"+link+"' download='MeuArquivo.txt'>Baixar arquivo</a>";
 // Indica que é para baixar e dá um nome para o arquivo ^

document.body.innerHTML += "<br/><a href='"+link+"'>Abrir link</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar **sessionStorage** ou **localStorage**.

Exemplos bem simples.

**sessionStorage**

```js
let resultado = [{"otima":1}, {"boa":2}, {"pessima":2}, {"regular":2}]

// Grava
sessionStorage.setItem("resultado", JSON.stringify(resultado));

//Le
let resultadoSession = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("resultado"));
```

**localStorage**

```js
let resultado = [{"otima":1}, {"boa":2}, {"pessima":2}, {"regular":2}]

//grava
localStorage.setItem("resultado", JSON.stringify(resultado));

// Le
let resultadoSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("resultado"));
```

***A diferença básica entre sessionStorage e localStorage é que o primeiro expira sempre que o navegador é fechado, o segundo se mantém.***